# No color in vim with SSH on Linux server

Tags: ssh, vim, vi

At work, I use SSH to remotely connect on servers to edit files. As I got quickly bored of vi, I built a local vim, years ago, and everything worked fine. As my profile is shared between almost all servers, vim run fine everywhere.

But now, I want to use vim on a server where my profile is not using the shared one. So I rebuilt vim locally. This time, I also needed to build ncurse. Using the same config files, everything works, except colours! I just get black, white, and some underlining, indicating that the syntax check is activated.

Here's the configuration of the different servers:

- AIX server with vim 7.2 => colors work
- Linux 2.6.32 with vim 7.2 => colors work
- Linux 3.10.0 with vim 7.4 => colors don't work

The two first servers use my shared home folder. So it might be linked to the way vim has been built/installed. Moreover, I can get colors using ls.

I already tried changing puTTY options, the `TERM` variable on the remote server and the content of `t_Co` in vim. But so far nothing worked.

The result of the command `infocmp | grep colors` is:

- `colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,` on the AIX
- `colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,` on the Linux 2.6.32
- `colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, ncv@, pairs#64,` on the Linux 3.10.0

Comment: It might help to see the output of  `:version` on the Linux machine. (And it's odd that you needed to build ncurses.)

Comment: Here it is:
`Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic
+autocmd
-balloon_eval
-browse
++builtin_terms
+byte_offset
+cindent
-clientserver
-clipboard
+cmdline_compl
+cmdline_hist
+cmdline_info
+comments
+conceal
+cryptv
+cscope
+cursorbind
+cursorshape
+dialog_con
+diff
+digraphs
-dnd
-ebcdic
+emacs_tags
+eval
+ex_extra
+extra_search
+farsi
+file_in_path
+find_in_path
+float
+folding
-footer
+fork()
+gettext
-hangul_input
+iconv
+insert_expand
+jumplist
+keymap
+langmap
+libcall
+linebreak
+lispindent
+listcmds
+localmap`

Comment: `-lua
+menu
+mksession
+modify_fname
+mouse
+mouse_dec
-mouse_gpm
-mouse_jsbterm
+mouse_netterm
+mouse_sgr
-mouseshape
-mouse_sysmouse
+mouse_urxvt
+mouse_xterm
+multi_byte
+multi_lang
-mzscheme
+netbeans_intg
+path_extra
-perl
+persistent_undo
+postscript
+printer
+profile
-python
-python3
+quickfix
+reltime
+rightleft
-ruby
+scrollbind
+signs
+smartindent
-sniff
+startuptime
+statusline
-sun_workshop
+syntax
-tag_any_white
+tag_binary
+tag_old_static
-tcl
+terminfo
+termresponse
+textobjects
+title
-toolbar
+user_commands
+vertsplit
+viminfo`

Comment: `+virtualedit
+visual
+visualextra
+vreplace
+wildignore
+wildmenu
+windows
+writebackup
-X11
-xfontset
-xim
-xsmp
-xterm_clipboard
-xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/home/mfleurance/vim/share/vim"`

Comment: `Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/local/include  -I/op/cbs/db/thalerv2/prg/srcro/acces/include -I/oracle/product/12.1.0.2_cli/rdbms/demo   -I/oracle/product/12.1.0.2_cli/rdbms/public -I/oracle/product/12.1.0.2_cli/plsql/public -I/oracle/product/12.1.0.2_cli/network/public -I/opt/cbs/db/thalerv2/prg/TSD/include -I/opt/cbs/db/thalerv2/dlv/srcro/acces/include -I/opt/cbs/db/thalerv2/prg/srcro/acces/include -I/opt/cbs/db/thalerv2/tst/srcro/acces/include -I/opt/cbs/db/thalerv2/int/srcro/acces/include`

Comment: `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/home/mfleurance/ncurses/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lelf -lnsl  -lselinux -lncurses -liconv -lacl -lattr -ldl`

Comment: It would probably have been better to edit that into your question instead of posting it as a series of comments. I don't see any reason why colors don't work based on that output, though.

Comment: I am new on SuperUser. Thanks for the advice :)
I think the problem is linked to the terminal. From what I saw, `ncv@` means 'No color video'. But I don't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

After having asked the administrator to install the ncurses libraries on the machine, I recompiled vim, and the issue got fixed.